# Induction as a theorem within the metatheory?

Tags: logic

That induction works seems obvious and yet it typically needs to be included as an axiom (as I understand it).

Would it be possible instead to start with a theory which doesn't include induction and then derive induction as a theorem within the metatheory?  Now a metatheory is typically conceived of as a theory about theories which is to say looking at a formal mathematical theory from the outside looking in.  What I'm suggesting is slightly different in that I would like to view the metatheory as an extension of the original theory.  In other words it would be a theory with knowledge about itself.

Start with a formal theory $X$. Then define the metatheory $M(X)$ in the following manner

1. All of the axioms of $X$ are axioms of $M(X)$
2. Define an injective function from formulas in the language of $X$ to objects in $X$ (this might not be possible for any arbitrary theory since the class of objects in X would have to be at least as large as the set of possible formulas which is $\aleph_0$)
3. Define an injective function from sequences of formulas in the language of $X$ to objects in $X$
4. Extend the language of $X$ so that for a formula $\phi$, '$\phi$' represents the object in $X$ which $\phi$ maps to using the function from 2) (this is assuming the quote symbol doesn't exist in the original language of $X$, otherwise you'd have to pick another symbol which doesn't exist in the language of $X$ to act as a delimiter)
5. Define the predicate $v(p,x)$ which is true iff $p$ is a sequence of formulas with 0 free variables (or more precisely can be mapped to a formula with 0 free variables using the inverse of the mapping from 3) representing a proof, $x$ is a formula  with 0 free variables (can be mapped to a formula with 0 free variables using the inverse of the mapping from 2) representing a theorem and $p$ is a valid proof of $x$
6. Define the predicate $t(x)$ which is true iff x is a a formula with 0 free variables representing a theorem which is provable within $X$ equivalent to $\exists p(v(p,x))$
7. Add one additional axiom to $M(X)$ which is
   $$\text{For each formula } \phi \text{ with 0 free variables }  t('\phi') \implies \phi$$

The motivation behind this idea is that it would hopefully allow you to turn a proof schema which is to say an algorithm for constructing a proof of any statement within a specific set of statements into a single proof for all of the statements.  This is particularly useful if the set of statements you are trying to prove is infinite.

Using Dan Christenen's formulation of induction below given a set $X$ with $x_0 \in X$ and function $S:X \rightarrow X$ such that $x \in X \iff x = x_0 \vee \exists x_1 \in X( x = S(x_1))$ we want to prove that $\forall P \subset X:(0 \in P \wedge \forall x \in P:S(X)\in P \implies P=X)$.  Now it seems that it would be quite easy to show for any given element $x_1 \in X:(0 \in P \wedge \forall x \in P:S(X)\in P \implies x_1 \in P)$ by simply applying the inductive rule repeatedly in the proof until $x_1$ is reached.  But if you could translate this proof schema into a proof that each statement corresponding to each possible value of $x_1$ is provable within the original theory then that would constitute a proof of induction in general within $M(X)$

Is $M(X)$ actually more powerful than $X$ in general (or in any specific case)?  What about M(M(X))?

Edit: Actually I see a proof of induction within ZFC directly in my textbook so the original premise of the question is completely wrong.
2nd Edit: After looking at it again I think I could apply this idea to ZF-Inf.  In my textbook the class of natural numbers is defined first and then the axiom of infinity is introduced in order to prove that the natural numbers form a set.  I think however you could prove induction on the class of natural numbers in M(ZF-Inf) using the method I described above.  Maybe it's possible in plain old ZF-Inf though as well not sure.

Comment: Your description of the process that leads from $X$ to $M(X)$ is unclear. Your first three paragraphs say nothing about the successor function $S(\cdot)$.

Comment: I've edited the post to try to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible instead to start with a theory which doesn't
> include induction and then derive induction as a theorem?

Yes. In general, induction will hold on any set $X$ with $~x_0\in X$ and function $f: X \to X$ such that $X=\{x_0, S(x_0), S(S(x_0)),~ \cdots~\}$ where $x_0$ is the *first element* and $S$ is the *successor function*. In other words, every element of $X$ but $x_0$ itself can be reached by a process of repeated succession starting at $x_0$.

**Example**

Consider $X = \{0, 1\},~S:X\to X, ~S(0)=1$ and $S(1)=0$

It is then trivial to prove by cases: $\forall P\subset X:(0\in P ~\land ~\forall x\in P: S(x)\in P
~\implies P=X)$

Hint: There are only 4 subsets of $X$ to consider.

Comment: The question is more about formal mathematical theories then when induction will hold in general.  I think what you're saying about when induction can hold is true and could perhaps be made even more general which is to say transfinite induction. It strikes me however that without relying on an axiom of induction the proof your setting up is really proving that induction works on a specific finite set.  I understand that you could use this method to prove that induction works for any particular finite set but even then you would have a proof schema rather than a single proof for all cases.

Comment: @Irishmanluke Well, since you asked, my proof for sets in general using a form natural deduction is given here: http://www.dcproof.com/InductionIffAccessible.htm (not for the faint of heart at 228 lines of formal proof)

Comment: Proof verification, nice